# Mover Javascript del head al footter en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Quiero poner todos los Javascript que aparecen en la cabecera de wordpress añadirlos en el footter para hacer la web más rápida, como debo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola, ya verificaste con alguna herramienta que el problema de rendimiento es por la carga de los javascripts?

Comment: Deben haber muchos plugins que hacen eso, ejemplo: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/scripts-to-footerphp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la función `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Por ejemplo, para pasar `jQuery` al *footer*, se haría algo asi:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' );

$handle = 'jquery'
$src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' 
$deps = array('jquery')
$version = '2.1.1'
$in_footer = false
wp_enqueue_script($handle, $src, $deps, $version, $in_footer);
```

En la primera línea, eliminas de la cola de scripts al `jQuery` que pone WordPress, porque lo pone en el *header*.

En la segunda línea registras un *script* para que vaya a la cola, los parámetros de esta función son los mismos que los de la siguiente:

La función que necesitas es `wp_enqueue_script` que toma cinco parámetros:

- **`$handle`** - Es el identificador del script, debe ser único y es obligatorio.
- **`$src`** - Es la ruta al script, es obligatorio
- **`$deps`** - Indica las dependencias que necesita el script para poder encolarse, es un array, pero es opcional.
- **`$version`** - Sirve para agregarle una etiqueta de versión, es opcional.
- **`$in_footer`** - Es un valor booleano *opcional*. Si es cierto se colocan antes de `</head>`, si es falso van antes de `</fotee33r>`.

En la vida real, el uso de estas funciones se ve asi:

```
/* *** jQuery 2.1.1 *** */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jQuery211', 99);
function jQuery211() {
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '2.1.1', false );
}
```

La función tiene algunas notas que debes conocer: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: y funciona perfectamente?es decir no se rompe wordpress ni el tema?

Comment: Y en que sitio tendria que poner este codigo?

Comment: Se pone generalmente en un plugin o en el archivo `functions.php` y evidentemente si se rompe WordPress o el tema, depende de ti, porque tu eres quien lo está pidiendo.